# DIV Displays Wider in IE8 works in FireFox, Safari, IE8 compat. Mode

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, width, alignment

I recently have attempted to add a line of "Social Media Icons" inside of a website. After creating a DIV and applying the properties everything looks fine in FireFox, Safari, and Internet Explorer 8 Compatability mode.

However, viewing the page in IE8 makes the DIV look like one pixel wider on the right-hand side. Also increasing the magnification in IE8 to 105% corrects the problem, yet this is hardly a satisfactory fix by my estimation.

**Website URL:** http://MikeChurch.com

**Cascading Style Sheet (CSS)**

```
    #wrapper{
```

width:960px;
 margin:auto;
}

```
    #banner{
```

width:100%;
 float:left;
}

```
    #socialMedia{
      background:#000000 no-repeat right top;
      border-bottom:5px solid white;
      border-left:5px solid white;
      border-right:5px solid white;
      overflow:hidden;
      float:left;
      width:99%;
```

}

```
   #wrap-container{
```

width:100%;
 float:left;
 background:#fff;
}

```
   #innerpad{
```

width:950px;
 float:left;
 padding:0px 5px 5px 5px;

**HTML**

    

`// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
include_once (dirname(__FILE__).DS.'/tmp_vars.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>"
lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>">
<head>
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<?php JHTML::_('behavior.mootools'); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $tmpTools->baseurl(); ?
>templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $tmpTools->baseurl(); ?  
>templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $tmpTools->templateurl(); ?>/css/layout.css"   
type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $tmpTools->templateurl(); ?>/css/modules.css"
type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $tmpTools->templateurl(); ?>/css/template.css" 
type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $tmpTools->templateurl(); ?>/css/joomla.css" 
type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $tmpTools->templateurl(); ?
>/js/jb.script.js"></script>

<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<script type="text/javascript">
var siteurl = '<?php echo $tmpTools->baseurl();?>';

window.addEvent ('load', makeTransBG);
function makeTransBG() {


fixIEPNG($$('img'));
 fixIEPNG ($$('#banner-top'), '', 'scale', 0, 2);
 fixIEPNG ($$('#banner'), '', 'scale', 0, 2);
 fixIEPNG ($$('#banner-bottom'), '', 'scale', 0, 2);

 }
 </script>

 <style type="text/css">
 .clearfix {height: 1%;}
 img {


border: none;
     }
     
     templateurl(); ?   


  /css/template_ie6.css" type="text/css" />        


 <![endif]-->

 <!--[if gte IE 7.0]>
 <style type="text/css">
 .clearfix {display: inline-block;}
 </style>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $tmpTools->templateurl(); ?
 >/css/template_ie7.css" type="text/css" />        

 <![endif]-->
 <!--[if gte IE 8.0]>
 <style type="text/css">
 .clearfix {display: inline;}
 </style>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $tmpTools->templateurl(); ?
 >/css/template_ie8.css" type="text/css" />        

 <![endif]-->
 </head>
 <body id="bg">
 <div id="wrapper">



        
     
     
     
     

 <a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/thekingdude"><img src="http://mikechurch.com/templates/mike_church/images/social_media_icons/twitter.jpg" title="Follow Mike on Twitter" alt="Follow Mike on Twitter" align="right" style="border:0"></a>

 <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/#!/TheKingDude?ref=ts"><img src="http://mikechurch.com/templates/mike_church/images/social_media_icons/facebook.jpg" title="Find Mike on Facebook" alt="Find Mike on Facebook" align="right" style="border:0"></a>

 <a target="_blank" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/MikechurchcomRssFeed"><img src="http://mikechurch.com/templates/mike_church/images/social_media_icons/rss.jpg" title="MikeChurch.com RSS Feed" alt="MikeChurch.com RSS Feed" align="right" style="border:0"></a>

 <div style="float:right;vertical-align:middle;">
<a target="_blank" href="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?       
 uri=MikechurchcomRssFeed&amp;loc=en_US"><span style="color:white; vertical-
 align:super">Keep up with the King Dude via eMaill RSS</span><img src="http://mikechurch.com/templates/mike_church/images/social_media_icons/rss_email.jpg" 
 title="Subscribe to MikeChurch.com RSS Feed by Email" alt="Keep up with the King Dude 
 via RSS email" style="border:0"></a></div>
  </div>
 <div id="innerpad">
     <div id="wrap-topnav">
         <div id="topnav">
             <jdoc:include type="modules" name="topnav" />
            </div>
            <?php if( $this->countModules('search') ){?>
            <div id="search-mod">
             <div class="padding">
              <jdoc:include type="modules" name="search" />
 </div>`

*Note: I have tried placing the DOCTYPE as the very first item in the HTML file, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

What happens there is that you said width='99%' which is subject to some rounding I believe and IE8 comes up with 1 extra pixel. You used a different technique for the div below, in order to obtain the white margin - a padding. On the social media div you used white borders with a width of 5px. IE counts the border width into the overall container width so if you'd say width=100% it would have been 10 pixels wider so I guess you chose 99% to make it closest to a right width.

I suggest you either use the same technique as in the "innerpad" div (paddings) or use an absolute width of 950px rather than a relative one.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to respond. My aptitude resides in design, but I am trying to learn CSS so as not to be a sloppy coder.

So yes adding a 100% width made the <Div> look wider on the right in FireFox but fine in IE, so it was really frustrating me to no end.

However, building off of your recommendation this is the updated CSS:

Comment: #socialMedia{
     background:#000000 no-repeat right top;
     border-bottom:5px solid white;
     border-left:5px solid white;
     border-right:5px solid white;
     overflow:hidden;
     }

Comment: I looked at the live site and it looks fine in that area. Is that the case?